# Cannot use jQuery with JSF RichFaces?

Tags: jquery, html, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to use jQuery on a page build with JSF and RichFaces standard, but no matter how I set, it doesn't work. In the code below, if jQuery works, it should directly pop up a warning dialog with "Debugging" txt on it. But it never happens.

I have looked at some links, like [How to enforce loading of jQuery in RichFaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587769/how-to-enforce-loading-of-jquery-in-richfaces), [How to use jQuery with JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667980/how-to-use-jquery-with-jsf-2-0), [Integrate JQuery with Richfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721960/integrate-jquery-with-richfaces), but even I declare same `<h:outputScript name="jquery.js" target="head"/>` in `h:header`, nothing happened.

Below is the full page, please help me to figure out, as jQuery is necessary for current task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head>
    <title>fttbDetails</title>
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" target="head"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
       content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="PED.css" library="css"></h:outputStylesheet>  
</h:head>

<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{fttbDetails.getFttbDetails}" />

<h:body>
<ui:include src="header.xhtml"></ui:include>
    <f:view>
    <h:form name ="fttbDetails" id ="fttbDetails">

    <table width = "100%">
    <tr>
        <td >
         <table width="100%" style="font-size: 11pt;font: normal">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height: 30px">
                    <td align="left" style="font-weight: bold;"><h:outputText value="FBS Restrict Ind"></h:outputText></td>
                    <td style="width: 5px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="fbsRestrictInd" value="#{fttbDetails.fbsRestrictInd}">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="Y" itemLabel="YES" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="N" itemLabel="NO" />                           
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </td>

                    <td style="width: 5px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" style="font-weight: bold;"><h:outputText value="FBS Restrict Reason"></h:outputText></td>
                    <td style="width: 5px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <h:inputTextarea style="width: 250px;height: 70px;" id="fbsRestrictRsn" value="#{fttbDetails.fbsRestrictRsn}">
                        </h:inputTextarea>
                    </td>

                    <td style="width: 5px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" style="font-weight: bold;"><h:outputText value="FBS Restrict Reason History"></h:outputText></td>
                    <td style="width: 5px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <h:inputTextarea style="width: 250px;height: 70px;" id="fbsRestrictRsnHistory" value="#{fttbDetails.fbsRestrictRsnHistory}" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}">
                        </h:inputTextarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 100px" >
                    <td colspan="3">
                    <rich:dataTable value="#{sessionScope.EquipList}" var="equip" columnClasses="column1"
                                  style="height:38px; width:95%;" rendered="#{not empty sessionScope.EquipList}" >
                        <rich:column style="text-align:center;width:100px;"> 
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Equipment"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{equip.equipClli}"/>
                        </rich:column> 

                        <rich:column> 
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Type"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{equip.equipType}"/>
                        </rich:column> 

                        <rich:column> 
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="SDN Ind"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{equip.sdnPortAvailability}"/>
                        </rich:column> 
                    </rich:dataTable>
                    <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.EquipMessage}" rendered="#{empty sessionScope.EquipList}" style="font-size:normal;color:blue;font-weight: bold"></h:outputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 50px">

                <td align="right" colspan="7">
                    <h:commandButton value="Update"  style="height:22px" id="update"  
                        onclick="if (! confirm('Do you want to update FTTB details?')) return false" action="#{fttbDetails.updateFttb}">
                    </h:commandButton>
                </td>
                    <td style="width: 5px">&nbsp;</td>  
                <td>
                    <h:commandButton value="Back" style="height:22px;align:right"  action="CplSearch.xhtml"></h:commandButton>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr></table></h:form></f:view>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
             alert("Debugging");
         });
    </script> 
</h:body>
```

Then I tested wether jQuery library is loaded [Checking if jquery is loaded using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341865/checking-if-jquery-is-loaded-using-javascript), I edit my script part as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function(){
    //     alert("Debugging");
    //});
    window.onload = function() {
        if(window.jQuery){  
            // jQuery is loaded  
            alert("Yeah!");
        } else {
            // jQuery is not loaded
            alert("Doesn't Work");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The effect is when page generated, the dialog show with "Yeah!", seems jQuery library already loaded ? But why original script part doesn't pop up dialog ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         alert("Debugging");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, did you really need to include such a lot of HTML? Seems like none of the HTML in the `<body>` is relevant to your question, so perhaps you might [edit] your question to cut it down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway, do you get any JS errors in the browser's console? Do the browser's dev tools' Sources and/or Network tabs (or equivalent) show whether Jquery loaded?

Comment: @nnnnnn, i have concise the file, delete unnecessary part, just keep some section used to show its feature, As I am quite new to front end, I didn't open the console to check, I am using chrome, will check if anything happen, thanks

Comment: @nnnnnn, i tested and edit the script part, it seems jQuery library loaded ? Then why change back to $(document).ready(..) doesn't work ?

Comment: Test with noconflict modus https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refer two documents [Difference between $(window).load() and $(document).ready() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready-functions), [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) and testing with my jQuery, the problem is on I should choose `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready`, jQuery library works fine when declared in header on `JSF/RichFaces` page, the pop up dialog will show up after changing to `$(window).load`.